# Adding a new parameter in the field base class

Tags: python, parameters, flask, addition, wtforms

I'm using `WTForms` with `Flask` and I need to add a new parameter in the field base class. Until now I used to assign a tuple to the `description` parameter by invoking a function which returns the desired tuple:

```
# app/forms.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import IntegerField
from wtforms import ValidationError
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired
from flask.ext.babel import lazy_gettext    

def descr(name):
    descrs = {
    'd': ('description', 'unit'),
    'h': (lazy_gettext('description2'), 'unit2'),
    # ...
    }
    return descrs.get(name, name)

class As(Form):
    d = IntegerField('d', default=210, description=descr('d'), validators=[InputRequired()])
    # ...

class BendingForce(Form):
    h = IntegerField(lazy_gettext('h'), default=250, description=descr('h'), validators=[InputRequired(), grater_than_cero])
    # ...
```

Now I would like to have two parameters `description` and `unit` to assign the desired values. How can I accomplish that ? Is it wise to do that anyway?

Example:

```
class BendingForce(Form):
            h = IntegerField(lazy_gettext('h'), default=250, 
                             description='description2', unit='unit2', 
                             validators=[InputRequired(), grater_than_cero])
            # ...
```